# What is sequence of fields in result document

Tags: solr

Does Solr maintain sequence of fields (Dynamic fields ) in result document like in the sequence used to index the document ?

**For Example:**

Consider the following record being indexed 
`School_txt` , `Class_txt` , `Section_txt`

So When I will get this document as a result , will the sequence of fields be maintained or it can be random like Class_tx , School_txt , Section_txt ?

If it can be random then how can I preserve the sequence of fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sequence of the fields are maintained (at least with 4.9.0) for each document. This is also true for multiValued field, where the values are returned in the same sequence as they are added (which is useful if you want to merge two fields into a separate value later). Here's an example where I rotated the field sequence while indexing:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "School_txt": "School",
    "Class_txt": "Class",
    "Section_txt": "Section1",
    "_version_": 1473987528354693000
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "Class_txt": "School2",
    "Section_txt": "Class2",
    "School_txt": "Section2",
    "_version_": 1473987528356790300
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "Section_txt": "School3",
    "School_txt": "Class3",
    "Class_txt": "Section3",
    "_version_": 1473987528356790300
}
```

Comment: I think Sequence maintained from  Solr4.4 onwards .. Anyways thanks for clearing my doubt.